# What parameters does "navigator.app.loadUrl" receive?

Tags: cordova

I am using Apache Cordova, and I stumbled across this function:

```
navigator.app.loadUrl(x,y)
```

On console.log, it is shown to be a function of:

```
function (url, props) {
  exec(null, null, APP_PLUGIN_NAME, "loadUrl", [url, props]);
}
```

However, I am clueless about what is "props" and can't find any documentation on it. Therefore, I am wondering if anyone knows where can I get any info (documentation would be best) regarding this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 /**
* Load the url into the webview or into new browser instance.
*
* @param url           The URL to load
* @param props         Properties that can be passed in to the activity:
*      wait: int                           => wait msec before loading URL
*      loadingDialog: "Title,Message"      => display a native loading dialog
*      loadUrlTimeoutValue: int            => time in msec to wait before triggering a timeout error
*      clearHistory: boolean              => clear webview history (default=false)
*      openExternal: boolean              => open in a new browser (default=false)
*
* Example:
*      navigator.app.loadUrl("http://server/myapp/index.html", {wait:2000, loadingDialog:"Wait,Loading App", loadUrlTimeoutValue: 60000});
*/
loadUrl:function(url, props) {
    exec(null, null, APP_PLUGIN_NAME, "loadUrl", [url, props]);
},
```

https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/cordova-js-src/plugin/android/app.js#L33-L49

Comment: Thanks a lot. Damn. Weird I couldn't find it